# Where to compare flash memory (internal memory) performance?

Tags: internal-storage, performance

I used some apps from Google Play ("Disk Speed / Performance Test" and "A1 SD Bench") to get some metrics for the internal storage (NAND flash memory) of my tablet.

I got +/- 25 MB/s reading, +/- 9 MB/s writing. This a tablet from 2012.

Is there a site where I can compare this results with similar devices to get a feel if this is normal or not?

Comment: You have a lists of devices and their r/w speeds in those apps

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје  True for "A1 SD Bench", but it only shows recent tested hardware. How can I check how my tablet compares to similar price-level/date-of-release devices?

Comment: I don't know how but I managed somehow to find list, I don't know exact process but it was list opened in browser. Try googling.

Comment: I did. If you find it again, do post it. Thanks